# how to compare 2 mouse positions in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i have this code:

```
un = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x1, y1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()





    Player(PlayerX, PlayerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

i want to use the mouse x and the mouse y coordinates in both cases to see which one is bigger but i cant really use the coordinates since one of them always turns out undefined, how do i go about achieving this?

Comment: i am trying to make a sort of slingshot and to change the direction i need to check if the mouse position decreases or increases so i can move the picture accordingly

Comment: hmm. sounds like you need to compare the mouse position in the last frame. Does your game require the mouse to be released an then the slingshot changes direction?

Comment: btw `event.pos` returns the mous position as a tuple, so why are you using `pygame.mouse.get_pos`?

Comment: @Punz Matiss's comment reminded me that you should get the mouse position once at the beginning of the frame and use that throughout the frame because mouse position returned by `pygame.mouse.get_pos` can change in between the frames which will give you inconsistent results.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default position for the mouse, that corresponds to the slingshot being aimed foward. Make it like:

```
defx = 30           #Default x coordinate example
defy = 30           #Default y coordinate example
```

Then whenever you are comparing, you just get the difference just like you said.
But if you need to have the last mouse position, you can also make it like this:

```
lx, ly, x, y = 0, 0, 0, 0          #It's probably better to use two arrays here
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            lx, ly = x, y         #This makes so that lx and ly are the last frame values of x and y  
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            x1, y1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

This way you can use lx and ly as the last x and y values.
I didn't really understand what you wanted to do on the mouse up part, but you can do the same using lx1 and ly1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will not work because you cannot simultaneously have mouse up and mouse down. What you can do is store the mouse position once when it is pressed down. Lets call this `heldDownMomentPosition`. Then on a mousebuttonup event anytime after that, you can calculate the difference between `heldDownMomentPosition` and current mouse position. This will give you the direction in which the slingshot bullet needs to go. I used this mechanism in a game I made a while ago, here it is with some modifications to make it minimal. It has a simple drag to make it stop too.

```
import pygame
    
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

slingShotBullet = pygame.Surface((40, 40)).convert()
slingShotBullet.fill((255, 255, 255))
pos = [300, 300]
vel = [0, 0]
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
heldDownMomentPosition = None

while True:
    dt = clock.tick(60) * 0.001 #delta time in s
    mousePressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if heldDownMomentPosition is None:
                if pygame.Rect(*pos, 40, 40).collidepoint(mousePos):
                    heldDownMomentPosition = pos[0] + 20, pos[1] + 20
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if heldDownMomentPosition is not None:
                vel = [heldDownMomentPosition[0] - mousePos[0], heldDownMomentPosition[1] - mousePos[1]]
                heldDownMomentPosition = None


    vel[0] *= 0.99
    vel[1] *= 0.99
    pos[0] += vel[0] * dt
    pos[1] += vel[1] * dt

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(slingShotBullet, pos)
    if heldDownMomentPosition is not None:
        pygame.draw.line(window, (255, 0, 0), mousePos, heldDownMomentPosition, 2)
    pygame.display.flip()
```